# How to Make a specific Select/List menu active automatically by selecting an option?

Tags: javascript, php, html

There is a piece of html code bellow.There will be two dropdown menu to show. First one to select a city, second one to select a restaurant corresponding the city. What I want is that,
1. Both select menu must be selected by any option, otherwise the button will not be able to perform any action.
2.To select a restaurant from second menu, A city must be selected from the first menu. Or it will show an error msg like"Select Your City First".
3.The second menu (restaurant_city) must show options based on selected city from first menu. for example; if I choose City_2 option, the second menu will only show all options from restaurant_city2 menu. In short, which restaurant menu will be active it must depend on the city selected.

Don't know how clear I have made myself. If anyone understand my problem, please help me solve it.
I know it will need some sort of programming like JS or PHP. I just want to know HOW ???

```
<select id="city">
       <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Select City</option>
           <option value="1">City_1</option>
           <option value="2">City_2</option>
</select> 

 <select id="restaurant_city1">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Restaurant</option>
        <option>Restaurant_1.1</option>
        <option>Restaurant_1.2</option>
        <option>Restaurant_1.3</option>
 </select> 

 <select id="restaurant_city2">
        <option value="" disabled selected hidden>Choose Restaurant</option>
        <option>Restaurant_2.1</option>
        <option>Restaurant_2.2</option>
        <option>Restaurant_2.3</option>
</select> 

<a class="btn_explore" href="#">Explore</a>
```

Comment: What is your server side? Do you have a Database of cities and restaurants, or is it a pure html solution?

Comment: I would use just 2 selects one for city and one for restaurant. When the page loads, the city select would be loaded as well. Then use javascript to detect when the user selects a city, make an ajax call to the server to get a list of restaurants for that city and populate the restaurant select dynamically.

Comment: If the best you got so far is _“I know it will need some sort of programming like JS or PHP.”_, then I think this question is massively too broad for this site. At that stage, you should be working through a couple of beginner’s tutorials to get a general feel for the techniques you are going to use, and do your own, proper research, how something like this can be accomplished. (It’s not exactly like this was a new requirement that no one ever faced before.)

Comment: @GeorgeDryser Currently it's just pure html. no database connected.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to use JavaScript or JQuery. In my example I'm just using JavaScript. You would need to find the `Id` of the `select` tags and do your work from there. You can just show and hide your options based off of the value of the city you chose. Also, I added in that if the user tries to select the 2nd drop-down item without selecting a city, then the restaurant drop-down will become disabled until a city is selected. I added similar functionality to the Explore button as well. Its to ensure both drop-downs are populated before clicking Explore. This was just a quick thrown together code, so its not the best code. But hopefully it can get you on the right track.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m8x6537n/4/